# Does native Android have a backup solution similar to iOS?

Tags: backup, restore

Does native (i.e. unrooted, non-unlocked, non-jailsomehowbroken) Android (later versions of it) have a backup solution *similar* to iOS (what used to be called iTunes backup, whatever it's called now) ?
That is allowing to essentially "clone" the phone/tablet across to another physical device. i.e. one simply cannot tell the difference when opening the cloned device, everything is the same on it, without having to re-login to all cloud apps, reconfigure things etc.

And before you go "*With Android, it depends on OEM*" -- well, OEMs base their derivative OS on Android anyway, hence the question mentioning "native" Android solution.

Note: ADB is *great* but is **NOT** equivalent nor similar to iOS backup, where "everything" is backed up (including sensitive data like keychain and health data, when password-enabled encryption is on) and that same "everything" is restorable to another iOS device. And no, **please** do not start iOS vs Android war in comments or answers, it's **not** the purpose of the question. The purpose is to find the answer to the above question.

Comment: Answer: [No](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4462913)

Comment: The android backup will transfer most data, but not all.  Any paid for apps require installation.  And in general, logins are not preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Well, TL,DR Version is no.

- Android as "native" AOSP has ADB Backup, which is far away from being complete and thus similar to iOS solution.
- Android as Google requires it by Vendors to be implemented (with Google Play Services) include the Google proprietary Backup Solution to backup to Google Drive with Google One. This is vendor-agnostic, so i have seen this on every smartphone yet. This also saves things you would expect to be saved, like settings, Apps, personal Data and Files and most important App-Data. But with App-Data there is a culprit: the developer of the App can specify, which data is to be included. So there can be cases, where the developer doesn't specify this for certain data (for whatever reason) and it doesn't get backuped.
- Vendors implement their own backup solution. Samsung e.g. does this, but based on what i experienced in the past those apps or integrated solutions are also not complete. They are limited what the system allows those apps by APIs.
- Android Custom Roms are increasingly using an open-source App called *Seedvault* as their backup/restore solution. By compiling and including it in the system, it can handle backups the same way the Google solution handles it. But the drawback with developers excluding their apps for Backups still exists here.